# Paint an Gradient on screen

Tags: dart, flutter

To implement a color picker, I want to draw a rectangle with a gradient of colors inside. I tried to use a container with a `DecoratedBox` but it didn't quite work, as I had to give it a width, and I wanted it to fill its parent.
What is the best way to draw a Gradient in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you already know how to draw a gradient and your question is more about how to make a `DecoratedBox` as big as possible.

If your `DecoratedBox` appears in a `Column` or `Row`, consider wrapping it in an [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) and setting the [`crossAxisAlignment`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html) to [`CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html).

If your `DecoratedBox` is a child of a widget that doesn't provide a size to its child (e.g. [`Center`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html)), try wrapping it in a [`ConstrainedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox-class.html) with a `constraints` of [`new BoxConstraints.expand()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/BoxConstraints-class.html). Here's an example:

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gradient Example',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Gradient Example'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: new DecoratedBox(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue]
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```